# Why is my compare function not sorting my objects by location and returning the same object array unsorted?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have JSON data.

```
[
 {
   "name" : "",
   "location" : "home"
 },
 {
   "name" : "",
   "location" : "office"
 }
]
```

I do not have this...

```
var = data [
     {
       "name" : "",
       "location" : "home"
     },
     {
       "name" : "",
       "location" : "office"
     }
    ]
```

I cannot use a function compare(a,b) to sort my data.  This does not work because I can't call data.sort(compare) which I would be able to call if my data wasn't in the form of JSON.

If I could use compare I could use this answer:
[Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

This solution does not work for me.  I have to open my data from a .json using FS.

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('./app/data/testData.json');
```

I would like to now wort my data by using obj.location in alpha order.  I tried asking this and people marked it off using a javascript solution (the compare function).  If you can explain to me how I can use that function with my JSON data, I will use that solution.  I have tried to implement it, it just doesn't do anything and leaves my data in the same order.

Can I convert my JSON data into a format that will be able to use the compare function?

EDIT TO SHOW CODE I CURRENTLY HAVE / TRIED
I have this based on the solution above and it doesn't sort the data.

```
function compare(a,b) {
   if (a.location < b.location)
     return -1;
   if (a.location > b.location)
     return 0;
   return 0;
 }

let dataSort = fs.readFileSync('./app/data/testData.JSON');
let dataParse = JSON.parse(dataSort);

dataParse.sort(compare);

console.log(dataParse);
```

This returns the exact same data set with nothing sorted by menu.

Comment: Original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187517/what-is-wrong-with-the-way-im-sorting-my-array-of-json-objects

Comment: And what was wrong with the marked duplicate?

Comment: Are you just wanting to do `let data = fs.readFileSync('./app/data/testData.json'); data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: I deleted the original to rephrase it.  I explained what was wrong with it

Comment: Do you understand that JSON is a *string representation* of a JavaScript object?  There is no such thing as a JSON object.

Comment: JSON is a string format. Sorting it without converting it to an array of objects will be very difficult and not worth anyone's time. If you're ok with converting it, then this is very much a duplicate of the answer you linked to. Otherwise... good luck.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  Any idea why when I do convert it using parse the answer given still doesn't sort?

Comment: your objects don't have a `menu` property...

Comment: That would make sense as well, edited out the typo and added a.location

Comment: You realize, your array is already in alphabetical order based on location, right?

Comment: yes of course - my real data set has 10+ other locations

Comment: Your code doesn't match the code you copied from. you turned a `1` into a `0`. https://jsfiddle.net/ggrjm80u/

Comment: dataParse.sort(function(x, y){
 return x.location  > y.location ? 1 : x.location < y.location ? -1 : 0;
});

Answer (score 0):

var myObject = JSON.parse(***load the file data here***);